# im getting "syntax error near unexpected token" error in my shell script

Tags: shell-script

when I run the particular command in a console it works fine but when I run using start script..it throws error.

```
#!/bin/bash
# chkconfig: 2345 20 80
# description: Description comes here....

# Source function library.
. /etc/init.d/functions

start() {
    # code to start app comes here
    # example: daemon program_name &
        daemon /root/amr/bin/LoggerServer &
        daemon /root/amr/bin/mediaController -i 192.168.117.119 &
        daemon /root/amr/bin/mstdaemon --daemon
        daemon /root/amr/bin/pcdaemon --daemon -i ens192 -f "udp && portrange 3000-8000 && not(src host localhost)" &
        daemon /root/amr/bin/stund &
        daemon /root/amr/bin/tdaemon &
        #/root/amr/bin/start.sh &
}

stop() {
    # code to stop app comes here
    # example: killproc program_name
        killproc LoggerServer
        killproc mediaController
        killproc mstdaemon
        killproc pcdaemon
        killproc stund
        killproc tdaemon
}

case "$1" in
    start)
       start
       ;;
    stop)
       stop
       ;;
    restart)
       stop
       start
       ;;
    status)
       # code to check status of app comes here
       # example: status program_name
        status LoggerServer
        status mediaController
        status mstdaemon
        status pcdaemon
        status stund
        status tdaemon
       ;;
    *)
       echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|restart}"
esac

exit 0
```

error :

```
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `src'
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: `ulimit -S -c 0 >/dev/null 2>&1 ; /root/amr/bin/pcdaemon --daemon -i ens192 -f udp && portrange 3000-8000 && not(src host localhost)'
```

command line run : `./pcdaemon --daemon -i ens192 -f "udp && portrange 3000-8000 && not(src host localhost)"`

Comment: I am pulling blanks about that `/root/amr` directory contents ? It is not something that I encountered before. Care to let me know what lies in that directory ?

Comment: all my executables located there

Comment: Might be some sort of quoting mishap, it seems to see that `&&` as a shell boolean. Maybe try single quotes instead of double, just in case?

Comment: same error for single quote

Comment: Which distribution and version is it? Just guessing: there's a function `daemon` in `/etc/init.d/functions` and it messes up the quoting while running the command.

Comment: I'm not on Linux (so I don't have the function library nor `daemon`), but the script is not producing any *syntax errors* for me when I try it (after commenting out the sourcing of the library).

Comment: 3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon May 5 11:16:57 EDT 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: @SureshKumar **all my executables located there** doesn't give me any information, but in that case what does `/root/amr/bin/pcdaemon` do functionality-wise ? Is it a server based firewall ? executable name is not coming up in any decent goggle search I attempted.

Comment: basically our own executable...which can be run as daemon as below  ./pcdaemon --daemon -i ens192 -f "udp && portrange 3000-8000 && not(src host localhost)"       in this case it works fine.

Comment: @SureshKumar, the distribution, not the kernel version. Given that there's `chkconfig`, I'll guess some Red Hat based system. RHEL, CentOS, Fedora, something else? Which version? And what is the `daemon` command, and what does it do?

Comment: this is was due to this not(src host localhost)...it shud have been !(src host localhost)...but after changing into this,,,,im getting this error now though the scripts runs  "/bin/bash: portrange: command not found"

Comment: @ilkkachu  it is rhel

Comment: The `daemon` function isn't very clever about quoting its args; it just uses `$*`.  Might want to file a bug report with Red Hat. Workaround is to give `daemon` a single argument, an executable shell script (first line `#!/bin/sh`) that you write yourself, which ends in an `exec` statement that runs what you want with the arguments you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking inside `/etc/init.d/functions` on an old CentOS system, the `daemon` function effectively runs

```
/bin/bash -c "[...] ; $*"
```

`$*` [expands to](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Special-Parameters) to the function's arguments, separated by spaces, effectively losing the extra quotes around "udp...localhost)". The result is given to a new shell, that sees the following:

```
/root/amr/bin/pcdaemon --daemon -i ens192 -f udp && portrange 3000-8000 && not(src host localhost)
```

and runs it as a command line. The `&&` is *not* quoted at this point, so it's interpreted by the shell where `foo && bar` means "run foo, then if it succeeds, run bar". As it happens the `not(src...` triggers a syntax error so nothing runs. Changing the `not` to a `!` will not help, because even though it removes the syntax error, the shell now runs `pcdaemon` with the arguments truncated and then tries to run a program called `portrange`.

Apart from having Red Hat fix the script, you could work around this by putting the `pcdaemon` command line in a script of its own (as suggested by 
[Mark Plotnick](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/294480/im-getting-syntax-error-near-unexpected-token-error-in-my-shell-script#comment516473_294480)), or by adding another set of quotes. With the current `daemon` function, I think this should work:

```
daemon /root/amr/bin/pcdaemon --daemon -i ens192 -f "'udp && portrange 3000-8000 && not(src host localhost)'"
```

(Though if someone were to actually fix the `daemon` function, then this would give the extra quotes to `pcdaemon`.)